# SQL table aliases inside embedded statements

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have this MS Access table `ClassHours`:

```
ID | Class     | Hours
---+-----------+------
1  | Chemistry | 4
2  | English   | 3
3  | Math      | 1
4  | Math      | 2
```

I calculate the percentage of hours spent per class category using this query:

```
SELECT Class, 100 * SumOfHours / (
    SELECT Sum(SumOfHours) FROM (
         SELECT ClassHours.Class, Sum(ClassHours.Hours) AS SumOfHours 
         FROM ClassHours GROUP BY ClassHours.Class) AS Table1) AS Percentage
FROM (SELECT ClassHours.Class, Sum(ClassHours.Hours) AS SumOfHours 
      FROM ClassHours GROUP BY ClassHours.Class) AS Table1;
```

As you can see, I'm trying to make alias `Table1` where I don't have to duplicate that long FROM statement. But if I make the last line, say, `FROM Table1`, I get an error. How do I get this alias to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May be making this harder than it really is. If you want the percentage of total hours by class category, consider:

```
SELECT Class, Sum(Hours) / (SELECT Sum(Hours) FROM ClassHours) * 100 AS Pct
FROM ClassHours
GROUP BY Class;
```